# update html content after clicking on icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, client-side

after clicking on the Celsius or Fahrenheit icon, i want to change the degree and the icon . What happens with me that its just updating it once.

html :

```
<ul id="list">
    <li></li>
    <li>&nbsp;<i class="wi wi-celsius"></i></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('#list li:nth-child(2)>i').click(function() {
    var temp = $('#list li:nth-child(2)');
    if ($(this).hasClass('wi wi-celsius')) {
        alert("C");
        var convertedTemp = parseInt(temp.text()) * 9 / 5 + 32;
        temp.html(Math.round(convertedTemp) + '&nbsp;<i class="wi wi-fahrenheit"></i>');

    } else {
        alert("F");
        var convertedTemp = (parseInt(temp.text()) - 32) / (9 / 5);
        temp.html(Math.round(convertedTemp) + '&nbsp;<i class="wi wi-   celsius"></i>');
    }
});
```

Comment: what is with the extra spacing at `temp.html(Math.round(convertedTemp) + '&nbsp;<i class="wi wi-   celsius"></i>');` between wi- and celsius and the one for fahrenheit..

Comment: i-element has always the same class, so it alsway enters if instead of else.

Comment: if you're adding the i element when someone clicks, there won't be an event handler attached to it. you need to use event delegation or just amend an existing element instead of creating a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you remove the element from the page. The event does not get hooked up to the new element that you add. So you need to use event delegation.

```
$('#list li:nth-child(2)').on("click", ">i" , function () {
```

The other option is do not replace the HTML, just replace the text and classes.

```js
$('#list li:nth-child(2)>i').click(function() {
  var icon = $(this).toggleClass("wi-celsius wi-fahrenheit"),
      li = icon.closest("li"),
      span = li.find("span"),
      num = parseFloat(span.text()),
      isCel = icon.hasClass('wi-celsius'),
      val = isCel ? num * 9 / 5 + 32: (num - 32) * 5 / 9;
  span.text(val);
});
```

```css
.wi-celsius::after { 
  cursor : pointer;
  content : "°C"
}

.wi-fahrenheit::after { 
  cursor : pointer;
  content : "°F"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li></li>
  <li><span class="num">32</span>&nbsp;<i class="wi wi-celsius"></i>
  </li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @MoaadAmer You add a click event to an element. You remove that element from the page and replace it with the new one. The new one does not magically get the event that you added to that other element. So you need to either rebind the click event to the new element. Or you use event delegation (add event to a parent and the parent checks to see if the click was on a child) so the event will be attached to dynamic elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would use JQuery's toggle class

```
$('#list li:nth-child(2)>i').click(function(){
  var temp = $('#list li:nth-child(2) > span.num');
  $(this).toggleClass("wi-celsius");
  $(this).toggleClass("wi-fahrenheit");

  if($(this).hasClass("wi-celsius")){
     var convertedTemp = parseInt(temp.text()) * 9 / 5 + 32;
  }else{
     var convertedTemp = (parseInt(temp.text()) -32)/ (9/5);    
  }

  $('#list li:nth-child(2)> span.num').text(convertedTemp);
});
```

This will just change them on each click.

Edit: works now by adding the span in @epascarello's answer

Comment: That wont work because i still have to check what is the class so i can update the degree respectively  not just the icon

Comment: @MoaadAmer - well of course but I just was fixing the class issue.

Comment: @MoaadAmer - Updated my answer to provide you more code

Comment: Actually run your code... You will see it has the exact problem as the OPs code. It will work once.

Comment: @epascarello ahh, I did it with my last line.